# C: Insert many chars into malloc-generated string

Tags: c, string

I have read in a tutorial that this is a valid way of creating a string:

```
char *ptr_to_str = malloc( sizeof(*ptr_to_str) * 256 );
```

But how do I fill this variable with a string?

```
*ptr_to_str = 'a';
```

Successfully changes the first char to 'a'. And I can print the string like this:

```
printf("%s",ptr_to_str);
```

output:

```
a
```

But when I try to change the next char, like this:

```
*ptr_to_str[1]= 'b';
```

I get an error "Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid).

What's going wrong here, AND how can I successfully insert a string of many chars into `*ptr_to_str`?

Comment: OT: The code misses to `0`-terminate the `char` array. As it stands it's not a C-string. Passing it to function expecting a C-string provokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: 1) C does not have a string type. A `char *` is not a string, nor an array. 2) This is a typical lesson in most C books. What does your's say? What is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says

> Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid).

here `ptr_to_str[1]` is the value at location `pt_to_str + 1` and you are putting a `*` before it `*ptr_to_str[1] = 'b'` (indirection) which is invalid, because `*` requires a pointer to operate with not a `int`/`char` value.

So modify your code to `ptr_to_str[1] = 'b';`

> Now how do I fill this variable with a string?

you can use `fgets(ptr_to_str, size, stdin);` or a for loop to manually initialize the array;

```
pt_to_string = malloc(size + 1); // declare 1 extra memory for null terminatior.
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ptr_to_string[i] = 'a'; // some char
}
ptr_to_string[size] = '\0';
```

You can also use `strcpy` to copy the value of another string to your char array:

```
strcpy (ptr_to_string, "copy string");
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `*` it doesn't mean anything

```
ptr_to_str[1]= 'b';
```

you are basically applying the dereference operator on non pointer type, which is why the compiler is throwing error.

Let's divide the following line in which you are confused:

`*ptr_to_str[1] = 'b'`

`char c = ptr_to_str[1];`

`*c = 'b'` // error because you are now dereferencing the non-pointer type as c is itself a char type.

And ofcourse you can create a string with following code if it is what you were asking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *ptr_to_str = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * 256 ),temp,ignore;
    int i=0,len=5;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&temp);
        scanf("%c",&ignore); // just ignore this line as it will be automatically skipped. 
        ptr_to_str[i] = temp;
        ptr_to_str[i+1] = '\0'; // never forget to end the string with null character
        printf("string so far : %s\n",ptr_to_str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`*ptr_to_str` is same of `ptr_to_str[0]`. So

```
ptr_to_str[1] = 'b';
```

This mean offset +1 from address of ptr_to_str. So you can do it with:

```
1[ptr_to_str] = 'b';
```

Comment: That's valid, yet does not realy answer the question. It also obfuscates the code; no sane programmer will write code like that.